# case with a $@ variable inside

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I want the following script to allow the user to select --header and then insert file* as the file name to add a header to all valid files.

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
--header )
  for filename in "$@"
  do 
  sed -i -e '1 e cat header' "$filename"
  done
  ;;
--footer )
  footer=~/dev/sed/footer
  for filename in "$@"
  do
  cat "$footer" >> "$filename"
  done
  ;;
esac
```

running the tool doing ./tool --header file* results in the following error:
sed: unrecognised option '--header'

I understand this is because of the $@ variable trying to match the first variable input (--header) but I'm not sure how to stop it

Answer (score 1):

To remove the first element from $@, use `shift`.

```
#!/bin/bash
opt=$1
shift
case "$opt" in
    --header )
        for filename in "$@" ; do 
            sed -i -e '1 e cat header' "$filename"
        done
    ;;
    --footer )
        footer=~/dev/sed/footer
        for filename in "$@" ; do
            cat "$footer" >> "$filename"
        done
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you are running your loop (over `"$@"`), the option is still the first element of the list that you loop over.  You may remove the first element of `$@` with `shift` before the loop.

---

I prefer to have my command line parsing and actions separated:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset do_header
unset do_footer

# loop until end of valid options...
while true; do
    case $1 in
        --header)   do_header=1 ;;
        --footer)   do_footer=1 ;;
        *)  # assume end of options
            break
    esac
    shift  # we have processed a valid option, shift it off the list
done

# create a temporary file that we will use multiple times
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

# remove temporary file on normal exit (in bash, also on TERM/INT)
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT

# For each file, copy it to the temporary file,
# then add header and footer as requested.
# Since we clobber the original file with the redirection, 
# we won't be modifying permissions on the file.

# At this point, the valid options (any number of
# --header and --footer options) have been shifted off
# the list of arguments, so the $@ array now presumably only
# contains pathnames of files that are to be modified.

for pathname do
    cp -- "$pathname" "$tmpfile"
    cat ${do_header:+"header"} "$tmpfile" ${do_footer:+"footer"} >$pathname
done
```

This additionally allows adding both header and footer to a set of files with one single invocation.

The parameter substitution `${var:+word}` expands to `word` if the variable `var` is set and not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you're using bash is

```
for filename in "${@:2}"
```

This will give you the arguments, starting with the second one. 
This is not specified by POSIX, so some systems might not support it. 
And some shells may have the same functionality, but use a different syntax.